# ResourceBundle.getString with fallback if key not found

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I am trying to find a way to use resource bundle with possibility of some kind of a fallback if the key is not found.
Currently the only way I have found is catching the exception:

```
try {
    resourceBundle.getString(key);
} catch (MissingResourceException ex) {
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Is there a nicer solution to this problem (something like `getOrDefault` in `Map`)? Maybe another library with nicer API?

Comment: @Lino It comes from standard Java library's https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ResourceBundle.html

Comment: ResourceBundles contain localized data for use by an application.  The application already knows what keys it will be looking up.  Therefore, it is not normal for a ResourceBundle lookup to fail.  Are you using ResourceBundle to hold configuration?  That is not what ResourceBundle is for;  use a regular Properties resource for that (which can have any number of fallback Properties).

Comment: @VGR some values are optional in UI application, like tooltips. For example I create button with key 'x' then I lookup 'x.label' and 'x.tooltip' in ResourceBundles. I could "hardcode" information about which UI element has tooltip or not, but by having optional value I can have simpler codebase and possibility to easily add resources when needed (also sometimes you might need tooltip in only one localization).

Comment: Ah, okay.  Then maio290’s answer is the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every data structure supports such a method. In your case, you'd normally check whether the key is contained or not by using the [`containsKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#containsKey-java.lang.String-) method.

Catching an exception as "normal" flow in the code is not what I'd call a decent architecture.